# Retrieve all rows using Left Join in Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am having issue on retrieving rows using left join in sub query having two different date range.

[Tables that i used to store values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLn8m.png)

And so far I used this sql to retrieve the output (Learnt from Stack overflow)

```
SELECT 
    TT.TransferRId, RM.ResourceName AS BookName, 
    COALESCE(Opening,0) AS Opening, 
    SUM(TT.InwardQty) AS Inward, 
    SUM(TT.OutwardQty) AS Outward, 
    COALESCE((Opening + (SUM(TT.InwardQty)) - (SUM(TT.OutwardQty))), 0) AS Closing
FROM 
    ((ResourceMaster RM 
LEFT JOIN 
    TransferTrans TT ON TT.TransferRId = RM.ResourceId)
LEFT JOIN 
    TransferRegister TR ON TR.TransferRegisterId = TT.TransRegisterId)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         TT.TransferRId,
         (SUM(TT.InwardQty)- SUM(TT.OutwardQty)) AS Opening
     FROM 
         TransferTrans TT  
     LEFT JOIN 
         TransferRegister TR ON TR.TransferRegisterId = TT.TransRegisterId
     WHERE 
         TR.TransferDate < '2018-09-01'
         AND TT.Siteid = 2 
     GROUP BY 
         TT.TransferRId) AS Stock ON Stock.TransferRId = TT.TransferRId
WHERE 
    TT.Siteid = 2
    AND TR.TransferDate BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
GROUP BY 
    TT.TransferRId, RM.ResourceName, Opening
```

[Output for Above Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooSGf.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GxTy.png)

Advise further to get the expected output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wbere is your `ResourceName ` colums in your sample data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, we would like to be able to copy and paste your table schemas and data from your question. That's impossible with pictures. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and, regarding posting pictures, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584

Answer (score 1):

The Where-condition on `TransferDate` changes the Left join to an Inner Join, move it to the On:

```
SELECT 
    TT.TransferRId, RM.ResourceName AS BookName, 
    COALESCE(Opening,0) AS Opening, 
    SUM(TT.InwardQty) AS Inward, 
    SUM(TT.OutwardQty) AS Outward, 
    COALESCE((Opening + (SUM(TT.InwardQty)) - (SUM(TT.OutwardQty))), 0) AS Closing
FROM 
    ResourceMaster RM 
LEFT JOIN 
    TransferTrans TT ON TT.TransferRId = RM.ResourceId
LEFT JOIN 
    TransferRegister TR
  ON TR.TransferRegisterId = TT.TransRegisterId
 AND TR.TransferDate BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         TT.TransferRId,
         (SUM(TT.InwardQty)- SUM(TT.OutwardQty)) AS Opening
     FROM 
         TransferTrans TT  
     LEFT JOIN 
         TransferRegister TR 
       ON TR.TransferRegisterId = TT.TransRegisterId
      AND TR.TransferDate < '2018-09-01'
     WHERE TT.Siteid = 2 
     GROUP BY 
         TT.TransferRId) AS Stock ON Stock.TransferRId = TT.TransferRId
WHERE 
    TT.Siteid = 2
GROUP BY 
    TT.TransferRId, RM.ResourceName, Opening
```

There's a rule of thumb which usually fits: Conditions on the Outer table are put in `WHERE` while conditions on the Inner table are `AND`ed to the join-condition in `ON`

Comment: if i comment AND TR.TransferDate BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30' also showing same result its suppose to filter the Inward and Outward Qty based the TR.TransferDate Between condition.

Comment: dnoeth, Can I create two dataset in VB.net and merge it into one dataset ?

Comment: It's hard to tell why you get your current result based on some pictures of data. It would be much easier if you create a fiddle with DDL & Inserts, e.g. on http://sqlfiddle.com/